# Remove/ disable the scrollbar of region in Oracle APEX

Tags: user-interface, oracle-apex

I created a prototype for my application. To make the application looks better, I decided to remove the scrollbar. Does anybody know how to make it?
[image: Charts with scroller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways (see screenshot, numbers "1" and "2"). Go to region properties, `User Interface` tab:

1. (**updated**) Choose template `Alert` and set property `Alert Icons` - `Hide Icons` to hide alert icon.

or

2. In `Standard` template, choose `Body Overflow` - `Hide` (as far as I remember, this option present only in Oracle APEX 5.0 and higher)

[image]

Comment: The first ways is work, but with Alert icon, therefore it is not applicable. I am using APEX 5.0.2.00.07, and from the second way, i found the way to disable the scrollbar. `Template Options -> Body Overflow Hide)`. Thanks for your feedback again.

Comment: @Jonas To hide alert icon, set property `Alert Icons` to `Hide Icons`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully changing the css style helps:

```
.a-GV-w-scroll {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

See the "inline-css" on [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+apex+inline+css&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01B6pQPH2T2zJU4Kfm9xNhOKr662g:1609336188528&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1g92-7PXtAhXDlYsKHWgyBEoQ_AUoAXoECAsQAw&biw=1920&bih=1086#imgrc=y-gUZLJJYl8OmM) page.